# Http caching in Android REST client (Virgil Dobjanschi's pattern A)

Tags: java, android, rest, http, caching

I'm writing Android REST client. I chose Virgil Dobjanschi's pattern A for this purpose, but I can't understand one thing. If I use Retrofit + SQL + ContentProvider, how can I check to see if ContentProvider's data is up-to-date?

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: I'm just trying to plan the structure of application. I want to use something like Virgil's pattern, but some data will be changed very often by another clients, so I can't use only local copy, I need to check, if this copy is fresh. How can I do this? I thought about using HttpResponceCache. But it doesn't look good with this pattern. Maybe I should send requests with "If-Modified-Since" header and if the server returns 304 I'll simply load data from DB without changes. I don't know, which practice is used by developers